# How do I divide a number stored inside a variable?

Tags: python

The program I am writing allows you to input any number and the program will identify if the number is a prime number or not.  However, I am getting an error as shown below.

I have been having trouble with this line of my code:

```
chosen = input("Input a number")
number = (chosen) / chosen
```

When I run it, here is the output:

```
Input a number1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\engineer2\Desktop\Programs\prime numbers.py", line 3, in <module>
number = (chosen) / chosen
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Here is the full code:

```
chosen = input("Input a number")
number = (chosen) / chosen
one = 1
if number == (one):
print ("Its a prime number")


else:
print ("Not a prime")



input ("press enter")
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string, not a number. You need to convert it to a number before you can do arithmetic with it.

Comment: If you're using python 3.x, `input` returns a string simliar to `raw_input` in python 2.7

Comment: Next time, please at least attempt to search for the error on Google before posting a question on StackOverflow (or you know, reason a little bit about  the error message, which pretty much tells you exactly what is wrong in this case).

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to try and convert the input into a number, float in this case would be explicit.

Keep in mind you should use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of input.

```
try:
    chosen = raw_input("Input a number: ")
    number = float(chosen) / float(chosen)
except Exception as e:
    print 'Error: ' + str(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to divide strings, convert to an int using `int()`.

```
try:
    chosen = int(input("Input a number"))
except ValueError:
    print('Not number.')
```

As a side-note, your algorithm for [checking primality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) is flawed, you need to check every number in the range of your number for no remainder division with `n` not just the **input**.

```
a = int(input("Input a number: "))  # Example -> 7
def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):   
        if n % i == 0: 
            return False
    return True

print is_prime(a)
>>> True

# One-liner version.
def is_prime(n):
    return all(n % i for i in range(2, n))

print is_prime(a)
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `input()` returns a string rather than a number.
you first need to convert `chosen` to a number with `chosen = float(chosen)`. Then mathematical operations should work just fine..

Answer (score -1):

`input()` function returns a `string` instead of an `int`. Try converting it or using `raw_input()` instead:

Method 1:

```
chosen = int(input("Input a number"))
number = (chosen) / chosen
```

Method 2:

```
chosen = raw_input("Input a number")
number = (chosen) / chosen
```

Comment: python doesn't have typecasting